# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'datasets/flowers/flower_photos'

Tags: python, machine-learning, transfer-learning

I follow the code on exercise 9.1 at https://notebook.community/me-surrey/dl-gym/.ipynb_checkpoints/13_convolutional_neural_networks-checkpoint, and here is the code:

```
flowers_root_path = os.path.join(FLOWERS_PATH, "flower_photos")
flower_classes = sorted([dirname for dirname in os.listdir(flowers_root_path)
              if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(flowers_root_path, dirname))])
flower_classes
```

but I got the error:`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'datasets/flowers/flower_photos'`
Does any one know how to fix this, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the directory exists ?
See if the directory actually exists
This could have been a comment but I dont have enough rep to comment

Hope this helps :)

Comment: yes, it is empty in the datasets/flowers directory on the Jupyter notebook, do you know how can I fix this

Comment: Well , I dont use jupyter notebook. Maybe try running the code on your own pc